Why does Python not allow Generics with isinstance checks?
Running the below code with Python 3.12.4:
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class Foo(Generic[T]):
    def some_method(self) -> T:
        pass

isinstance(Foo[int](), Foo[int])

It will throw a TypeError: Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/a.py", line 9, in <module>
    isinstance(Foo[int](), Foo[int])
  File "/path/to/.pyenv/versions/3.12.4/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/typing.py", line 1213, in __instancecheck__
    return self.__subclasscheck__(type(obj))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/path/to/.pyenv/versions/3.12.4/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/typing.py", line 1216, in __subclasscheck__
    raise TypeError("Subscripted generics cannot be used with"
TypeError: Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks

What was the rationale for Python not allowing isinstance checks with Generics?

Because an instance contains no reference to its instantiated-generic-type. At runtime Foo[int]().__class__ is Foo[str]().__class__ is Foo.

At runtime, type arguments are not verifiable. Such relationships are only checked at type-checking time:

Note that the runtime type (class) of [the variables given as example] is still just Node – Node[int] and Node[str] are distinguishable class objects, but the runtime class of the objects created by instantiating them doesn't record the distinction. This behavior is called "type erasure"; it is common practice in languages with generics (e.g. Java, TypeScript).
— Generics - Specification for the Python type system

For example, if isinstance(..., list[str]) were to be treated at isintansce(..., list), the result would be very confusing:
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> isinstance(a, list[str])
True

Also consider the case where type arguments are not concrete:
def is_list_of(v: Any, element_type: type[T]) -> TypeIs[list[T]]:
    return isinstance(v, list[T])  # ???

This has always been the case since PEP 484, albeit not very explicitly (Callable and Generics are two different sections, and this note seems to mean something slightly different than what we are taking it to be, though conceptually the same):

[...] isinstance(x, typing.Callable[...]) is not supported.

However, there are runtime type checkers that do this kind of heavy-lifting, such as Pydantic.
Historically, the PEP 484 note was added in this commit, and type-erasure-related problems were discussed in this GitHub issue. It seems that GvR and other contributors were initially opposed to Node[int]() (which then worked at runtime but very slow, and was forbidden by Mypy) due to performance problems.

As mentioned in this answer, unfortunately it is not possible to type check generics at runtime. But if your use case to assert types for type checkers like my in case, this is what I came up with:
def istype[T](__obj: Any, __typ: type[T]) -> TypeGuard[T]:
    """Return typeguard assuming object is an instance of given type"""
    return True

Note that this doesn't do any type checking at all actually. But suppose an object has type Any and you want to tell type-checker that it's type is MyType instead then you can use it like this:
x = some_external_func()  # now type-checker treats x as having type Any
assert istype(x, MyType)  # now onwards type-checker will treat x as having type MyType

This is similar to typing.cast but with a broader area of influence rather than just the current expression.
